# How to only show fullscreen button in native html video element?

Tags: html

I have a simple video element:

```
<video width="500px" src="..."></video>
```

I only want to show one control on the element, the fullscreen button, how would I do this? The `controls` attribute either hides or shows all controls, while the `controlslist` element has no option for only one control.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do that with CSS. There are some options to use [video::-webkite-media-controls-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions)

You can remove them one by one using below CSS codes.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
  
}
```

Full sample;
https://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/abWGBMr